# javax.mail.Part and writeTo, unable to obtain the same "eml" file as the original one

Tags: encoding, jakarta-mail

My application parses many messages via javamail 1.5.6, it listens for incoming messages then store some info about them.

Almost all messages contain a digital signature, so my application needs to retrieve the full eml too, that is the raw file representing an email, in this way application users can always prove the validity of these messages.

So, once I have a javax.mail.Message, then I have to produces its eml, so I do:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
m.writeTo(baos);
this.originalMessage = baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

this approach generally works, but I had some multipart messages having part like the following:

> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>   --------------55D0DAEBFD4BF19F87D16E72 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-15; format=flowed Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> In allegato si notifica ai sensi e per gli effetti dell'art. 11 R.D. 
>   1611/1993, al messaggio PEC, oltre alla Relata di Notifica e
>   contestuale  attestazione di **conformità**,
>   --------------55D0DAEBFD4BF19F87D16E72

word "conformità" is not properly transformed in the resulting string, it becomes "conformitï¿½", opening such eml for example with MS Outlook results in an invalid digital signature, so message appears corrupted, different from the original

Have you same idea? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw message is **not** a UTF-8 encoded string, nor is an "eml" file a UTF-8 encoded file.  They are both byte streams, and your digital signature should work on byte streams.

In your particular example, the content of the message part is encoded using the iso-8859-15 charset, not UTF-8.

Comment: Ok, I made an error of understanding, because for some strange reason I was  convinced about the fact that to generate that kind of file from a byte stream, I needed to generate a text file, so I needed to specify charset.
Thanks again.

The simple use of a FileOutputStream should be the solution.